# uninitialized constant Twitter::OAuth - Overlooking a require somewhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth

I'm looking to use the latest Twitter gem for a Rails app I'm working on.

However, executing the following line:

```
oauth = Twitter::OAuth.new(ServiceAPIKeys.twitter['api_key'], ServiceAPIKeys.twitter['secret_key'])
```

Triggers the following exception:

```
uninitialized constant Twitter::OAuth
```

I do have the gem configured in my environment.rb using 'config.gem 'twitter'' and I have the gem unpacked into my vendor/gems directory.  I've also tried tossing a 'require 'twitter'' inside the controller where I'm calling it.

Am I missing something obvious or is this an issue with the current gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found.  There was another included gem, 'Twitter4r' that was using the Twitter namespace and it was taking precedence over the Twitter gem.

Comment: this might help someone http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-twitter-gem/browse_thread/thread/be600e4ffc5f6646?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me (Twitter4r is not installed on my system) is inserting  "gem 'twitter'" like in:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'twitter'    <<--- INSERT THIS
require 'twitter'
```